# Is there a best-known implementation for a Number Theoretic Transform on the 257 (2^8 + 1) finite field?

Tags: fft, ntt

I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to implementing FFTs in general, but I have most of the basic ideas down I think.  In this specific case, I've an implementation of the number theoretic transform on the 257 finite field.  It's basically your typical Radix-2 Cooley-Tukey FFT.  What Id like to know is either: is there a good alternative to the Cooley-Tukey Radix-2 that's better suited to doing this particular NTT efficiently (if the answer is an unqualified yes or a yes conditional on something not entirely within the scope of this question, I'm interested in hearing about either), or are there things specific to a Mersenne NTT that allow for a more efficient implementation than a more general case?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that for dyadic length FFT there is nothing better than Cooley-Tukey.

---

This has nothing directly to to with Mersenne numbers, any number field with modulus `2^(m*2^n)+1` qualifies. `I=2^(m*2^(n-1))` is the complex unit, `I^2=2^(m*2^n)=-1 mod (2^(m*2^n)+1)`, and `q=2^(2*m)` is a primitive `2^n`-th root of unity.

For inspiration for the second point see Section 1 of [Schönhage: Asymtotically fast algorithms for the numerical multiplication ...](http://www.iai.uni-bonn.de/~schoe/publis.html#n39), with overall [summary of fast multiplications](http://www.iai.uni-bonn.de/~schoe/topics.html)

Comment: It's been a while, but I keep coming back to this question.  You've said that "for dyadic length FFT there is nothing better than Cooley-Tukey"... why is that/what should I read in order to understand why this is?

Comment: DFT and its inverse is a special case of multi-point evaluation and interpolation. The best known algorithms for that are O(n*log(n)) (essentially, omitting additional loglog factors). Cooley-Tukey has the smallest factor in that complexity estimate. The only point to optimize is to chose when to cut off and "unroll" the recursion, at length 16, 8 or 4.

Comment: That's useful to know; do you know of a good source to read that does some explicit comparisons between Cooley-Tukey and, perhaps, Bruun's and Rader's FFT algorithms (and any others of significance)?